# Firebase insert data using Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am trying write Hello world kind of basic application with Firebase and Nodejs.

**Application code**

```
#cat app.js

var express = require('express');
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var app = express();
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  f(); 
  res.send("success");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

  var onComplete = function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Synchronization failed');
  } else {
    console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
  }
};

function f() {
var ref = new Firebase("https://dazzling-torch-XXXXX.firebaseio.com");
ref.set({
  location: {
    city: "San Francisco",
    state: "California",
    zip: 94103
  }
},onComplete);
ref.child("location/zip").on("value", function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());  // Alerts "San Francisco"
});
}
```

Library versions -

```
npm --version && node --version && firebase --version
1.3.6
v0.10.42
2.2.1
```

Node command -

1. node app.js
2. open browser http://localhost:3000/

**Debugger Output**

```
p:0: Making a connection attempt  
c:0:17: Connection created  
c:0:17:0 Websocket connecting to wss://dazzling-torch-XXXX.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5  
c:0:17:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.  
c:0:17:0 Network error: wss://dazzling-torch-XXXX.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5: getaddrinfo ESRCH  
c:0:17:0 WebSocket is closing itself  
c:0:17:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.  
c:0:17: Realtime connection failed.  
c:0:17: Closing realtime connection.  
c:0:17: Shutting down all connections  
p:0: data client disconnected  
p:0: Trying to reconnect in 17797.816018858393ms
```

but it is not updating firebase data. I am using default security rules.

Thanks
Pari

Comment: Any error message? What do you get when you make a request to / route?

Comment: `ref.set()` takes an optional second callback function that will be called in case of any errors (see [the docs for info](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html)). Setting that and logging the errors might show a hint as to what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added debugger .

Debug output -
c:0:2: Connection created  
c:0:2:0 Websocket connecting to wss://dazzling-torch-1380.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5  
c:0:2:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.  
c:0:2:0 Network error: wss://dazzling-torch-1380.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5: getaddrinfo ESRCH  
c:0:2:0 WebSocket is closing itself  
c:0:2:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.  
c:0:2: Realtime connection failed.  
c:0:2: Closing realtime connection.  
c:0:2: Shutting down all connections  
p:0: data client disconnected

Comment: Added onComplete callback function for set and debugger output in main post.

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, but the output of my steps is below.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran on node v0.10.37 and firebase 2.4.2 (those are really the only versions that should matter) and it connected and wrote the data instantly.

```
node app.js
Example app listening on port 3000!
p:0: Browser went online.
0: set {"path":"/36518762","value":{"location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"California","zip":94103}},"qh":null}
p:0: Buffering put: /36518762
p:0: Listen called for /36518762/location/zip default
event: /36518762/location/zip:value:94103
94103
p:0: Making a connection attempt
c:0:0: Connection created
c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.
c:0:0: Reset packet received.  New host: s-usc1c-nss-158.firebaseio.com
c:0:0: Shutting down all connections
c:0:0:0 WebSocket is being closed
c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
c:0:0:1 Websocket connecting to wss://s-usc1c-nss-158.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=stackoverflow
c:0:0:1 Websocket connected.
c:0:0: Realtime connection established.
p:0: connection ready
p:0: reportStats {"c":{"sdk.js.2-4-2":1}}
p:0: {"r":1,"a":"s","b":{"c":{"sdk.js.2-4-2":1}}}
p:0: Listen on /36518762/location/zip for default
p:0: {"r":2,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/36518762/location/zip","h":""}}
p:0: {"r":3,"a":"p","b":{"p":"/36518762","d":{"location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"California","zip":94103}}}}
p:0: from server: {"r":1,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
c:0:0: Primary connection is healthy.
p:0: handleServerMessage d {"p":"36518762/location/zip","d":94103}
p:0: from server: {"r":2,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}}
p:0: listen response {"s":"ok","d":{}}
p:0: from server: {"r":3,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
p:0: p response {"s":"ok","d":""}
Synchronization succeeded
```

It looks like your web socket is getting rejected way before that. You might want to check for proxies in between your client and the Firebase server. Try on a different network, that sort of thing.

- Try [the diagnostic page](http://www.firebase.com/test.html)
- ping INSTANCE.firebaseio.com
- tracert INSTANCE.firebaseio.com
- Run [this curl command](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/b7aa394e0dadfd538c57), substituting your Firebase URL at the end (don't forget .json!).
- Try a different computer on a different network

Note that these are all just steps to help you troubleshoot connection problems.

Comment: Thanks Frank, your steps did help.
It was problem with my internet provider.
I have launched AWS instance with node.js installed. My program is working without any error on aws instance.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer but as I don't have enough points, I could not do it. :(.